# Logging in Java 8 Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have some code where I'm using Java 8 `Optional` in which I want to `log` an error when I don't get the required result.

As shown in following Example I have `commented` on a line where I get the error when I'm trying to log `Error Message`:

```
    @PutMapping("/organs/{id}")
    public Organ updateorgan(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long organId,
                                           @Valid @RequestBody Organ organDetails) {

        Organ organ = organRepository.findById(organId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> 
                   // LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"Organ with id "+organId + "not found");
                   new ResourceNotFoundException("organ", "id", organId)
                );

        organ.setName(organDetails.getName());
        Organ updatedOrgan = organRepository.save(organ);
        LOG.info("Updated organ details. Response :"+updatedOrgan);
        return updatedOrgan;
    }
```

P.S - I only want to use the `Java 8` method and not conventional approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use enclosing braces `{}`

Comment: @Naman I tried using that the problem was I have not used `return` keyword. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: What would be better in terms of implementation is to get rid of the log in your code altogether. The primary reason being, the same message would be logged anyway based on your code when the exception is thrown. The stack trace/handling of the exception would be further meaningful for such case.

Comment: Yes that's true... But I was implementing ELK stack for visualizing logs and work around. The error was not logged in that case, so I was finding a way out @Naman

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Make it a lambda with a body enclosed by curly braces and a `return` statement instead of an expression lambda:

```
Organ organ = organRepository.findById(organId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"Organ with id "+organId + "not found");
                    return new ResourceNotFoundException("organ", "id", organId);
                });
```

Comment: Ohh! Thanks, I forgot to use `return` keyword so the error @Jesper

Comment: flawless answer!

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `return`

```
Organ organ = organRepository.findById(organId)
        .orElseThrow(() -> {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE,"Organ with id "+organId + "not found");
            return new ResourceNotFoundException("organ", "id", organId);
        });
```